# How is the "InputObject" Null?

Tags: powershell

I have had a script that has been running for the last 2 years just fine on the server. Suddenly this past week, ive been getting the following error logged:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\Scripts\Export_Usage_CSV.ps1:162 char:17
+ ... geResults | Export-Csv -Path $Usage_file_Path\CUBE_USAGE.csv ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Scripts\Export_Usage_CSV.ps1: line 162
Exit Code: 1
Failed!
```

The main portions regarding this code:

```
Function Query($Query) {
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$Server;Initial Catalog=$Database;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query 
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet 
$a=$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close() 
$DataSet.Tables[0] } 

$UsageResults = Query "SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES [SERVERNAME]
      ,[SESSION_ID]
      ,[SESSION_SPID]
      ,[SESSION_CONNECTION_ID]
      ,[SESSION_USER_NAME]
      ,[SESSION_CURRENT_DATABASE]
      ,[Business_Name]
      ,[SESSION_USED_MEMORY]
      ,[SESSION_PROPERTIES]
      ,[SESSION_START_TIME]
      ,[SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME_MS]
      ,[SESSION_LAST_COMMAND_START_TIME]
      ,[SESSION_LAST_COMMAND_END_TIME]
      ,[SESSION_LAST_COMMAND_ELAPSED_TIME_MS]
      ,[SESSION_IDLE_TIME_MS]
      ,[SESSION_CPU_TIME_MS]
      ,[SESSION_LAST_COMMAND_CPU_TIME_MS]
      ,[SESSION_READS]
      ,[SESSION_WRITES]
      ,[SESSION_READ_KB]
      ,[SESSION_WRITE_KB]
      ,[SESSION_COMMAND_COUNT]
      ,[UPDATE_TIME]
  FROM [dbo].[$Usage_Table]
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SESSION_ID ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME DESC)";

$UsageResults | Export-Csv -Path $Usage_file_Path\CUBE_USAGE.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

What i noticed is that the csv file gets created, however, it remains completely empty.

[image: csv file 0kb]

So i thought it must be that `$UsageResults` is empty which would explain the NULL.
So i commented out `| Export-Csv -Path $Usage_file_Path\CUBE_USAGE.csv -NoTypeInformation` and expected `$UsageResults` not to print anything to confirm my hypothesis.
But it DID print!!
it was printing out record by record on the console what is stored from the Query!

I thought maybe the csv export has a limit or something on the number of records, so i changed it to export to a txt file, and the same thing! The txt file was created but it remained empty!

What could be happening? There has been absolutely no changes to the script, all of a sudden this started happening this week...

I have another export in the csv very similar to the CUBE_USAGE one, and its exporting just fine as you can see from the image above (***PBI_USAGE, 10k KB***)

```
$PBI_Query_Result | Export-Csv -Path $Usage_file_Path\PBI_USAGE.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

We also have this script running on a test environment and its exactly the same by comparison, yet the issue is not happening there!!

Comment: At least _one of_ the items in the `$UsageResults` collection is `$null`. Try `$UsageResults |Where-Object{$_ -is [object]} |Export-Csv ...`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen what do i put for object?

Comment: It's not a place-holder, that's the literal expression :) - `$null` is the only operand for which `-is [object]` would ever return false

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen oh interesting lol. btw i tried `$UsageResults |Where-Object{$_ -is [object]} |Export-Csv ...` but still resulting in same issue

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen what i expect at the very least is the file should be more than 0KB. it should populate something in the file, even if one of the items is $null as we presume (which i didnt see as the case when it was printing the records on the console)

Comment: Very interesting - does the value of `$UsageResults.Rows.Counts` correspond to the actual number of rows you see printed in the console?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen running it now, lets see...btw i have added a screenshot of the files created (csv and txt for the different export options ive tried showing same result). It shows the PBI one as well but getting populated just fine...

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it didnt print out any count. instead i got this error: `Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.+ $a=$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
at Query,"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i removed the s from counts `$UsageResults.Rows.Counts` and it printed 0....

Comment: So the query doesn't actually succeed? That would explain :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen but that doesnt make sense...it printed to console before all the results...could this be a timeout issue given the above message?

Comment: Been following this. I think @MathiasR.Jessen is correct.  I'm able to repro by sending a null down the pipeline to `Export-Csv` I can intermingle `$null` in an object array to get the error, but the resulting file will have the objects prior to the null. In your case you are getting a 0 byte file, hence the whole object must be null. Moreover, it would explain why `$_ -is [Object]` didn't return anything. As for why the arr echoed to the screen there must be some other explanation. Perhaps a scoping issue? Given the line# I'd imagine there's more code...

Comment: @Steven there is more code indeed, but its unrelated to this cube usage one. The remaining code is the pbi usage one...I commented out the piped export from `$UsageResults` which is how it started printing the cube usage query records directly on console instead of file, which is what confused me since I had thought it must be that `$UsageResults` is Null initially...however, I started getting a timeout error afterwards as reported in prior comment...could it be an intermittent connection failure? Rarely it works but most of the time it times out? The PBI query prints just fine though...so idk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was indeed a Timeout Issue.

I had to add the following to my Query function to increase the timeout a little, because the default is 15 seconds according to [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#remarks).

```
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout=60
```